# How to convert XSSF color to Java.awt.color format. because XSSF colour could not make a compare

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have posted the code clealy . 
I want get the color of cell in excel, and i post my excel file and there are only two colors ,green and yellow. 
if I use XSSFColor ,the print out is XSSFColor@8b21b8fa and XSSFColor@dfcdb1. therefore, and I could not make a compare whether it is green or yellow.
I hope to print out 1 if it is yellow, and 0 if it is green. thanks for any help!!!

```
for(Row row : sheet)
{
    for(Cell cell : row)
    {
        switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
               Color cellColor= cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
               if(cellColor==Color.GREEN)
               {
                   System.out.print(0+",");
               }
               else if(cellColor==Color.YELLOW)
               {
                   System.out.print(1+",");
               }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[this is my excel file shows a madarin character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ngr.png)

Comment: Would something like [XSSFColor.getARGBHex()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor.html#getARGBHex%28%29) not do you - that'll give you a string like `00FFFF00` for your colour

Comment: Thank u. I have figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to create a `XSSFColor` from a `java.awt.Color`, there is no simple possibility to get  `java.awt.Color` from a `XSSFColor`.

We could compare the `ARGBHex` of the `XSSFColor` out of the cell with the `ARGBHex` of a new created `XSSFColor` from a `java.awt.Color`.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;

class ColorTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("ColorTest.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Row row : sheet) {

    for(Cell cell : row) {

     switch(cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
       Color cellColor= cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
       if (cellColor instanceof XSSFColor) {
        XSSFColor xssfCellColor = (XSSFColor) cellColor;
        if(xssfCellColor.getARGBHex().equals(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.GREEN).getARGBHex())) {
         System.out.print(0+",");
        } else if(xssfCellColor.getARGBHex().equals(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.YELLOW).getARGBHex())) {
         System.out.print(1+",");
        }
       }
      break; 

     }
    }
   }
   System.out.println();
  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

But in your provided picture the green color seems not to be really green with RGB 00FF00 but a muddy mixture green. So the comparision with `java.awt.Color.GREEN` will not match, since `java.awt.Color.GREEN` **is** exactly RGB 00FF00.

Example for both `XSSF` and `HSSF`:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

class ColorTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("ColorTest.xlsx");
   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("ColorTest.xls");

   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Row row : sheet) {

    for(Cell cell : row) {

     switch(cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
       Color cellColor= cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
       if (cellColor instanceof XSSFColor) {
        XSSFColor xssfCellColor = (XSSFColor) cellColor;

        System.out.println(xssfCellColor.getARGBHex()); 

        if(xssfCellColor.getARGBHex().equals(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.GREEN).getARGBHex())) {
         System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + " is green");
        } else if(xssfCellColor.getARGBHex().equals(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.YELLOW).getARGBHex())) {
         System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + " is yellow");
        }
       } else if (cellColor instanceof HSSFColor) {
        HSSFColor hssfCellColor = (HSSFColor) cellColor;

        System.out.println(hssfCellColor.getHexString()); 

        if(hssfCellColor.getHexString().equals("0:FFFF:0")) {
         System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + " is green");
        } else if(hssfCellColor.getHexString().equals("FFFF:FFFF:0")) {
         System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + " is yellow");
        }
       }
      break; 

     }

    }
   }

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank u Axel ! I got your point. but I think there are some problems in switch statement, did u test your code?

Comment: switch(cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:

Comment: Yes? Works for me. It will check if the cell is blank.

Comment: It also works for me.   if (cellColor instanceof XSSFColor) {XSSFColor xssfCellColor = (XSSFColor) cellColor;   could u explain this two piece of code?

Comment: Until this I'm working with `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*` only. This is reliable for both `HSSF` and `XSSF`. But now I need `XSSFColor` which is `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel`. So I must check if I really have a `XSSFColor` (`if (cellColor instanceof XSSFColor)`) and if so, cast the `cellColor` to `XSSFColor`. If `HSSF` (*.xls) will also be possible, then `} else if (cellColor instanceof HSSFColor) { HSSFColor hssfCellColor = (HSSFColor) cellColor;...}` will be necessary.

Comment: So I must check if I really have a XSSFColor (if (cellColor instanceof XSSFColor). can i understand this like that----whether cellColor is a instance of XSSFColor?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: OK, did u find that there is a null string.after print out a character. but after taht , there is no null string which i need.  but I could not find what is the problem.  I want represent a character and have a null string and then repensent another character

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks for all your assistance. Axel !

Comment: You could re-write the `XSSFColor` check to `ExtendedColor` to stick with only HSSF and SS classes if you wanted - `XSSFColor` implements that

Comment: @Gagravarr: No. The aim was to compare the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color`with `java.awt.Color`. This is not possible using only `ExtendedColor`. Furthermore with `HSSF` the `Color cellColor= cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();` is not instance of `ExtendedColor`. So both `XSSFColor` and `HSSFColor` are needed. But with `HSSF` seems not be possible to compare with `java.awt.Color`. See my supplements.

Comment: HSSF cell style colours are not ExtendedColors. However, if you want to write you code with only `org.apache.poi.ss` classes, the check for XSSF-like colours should be with `ExtendedColor`

Comment: @Gagravarr: How will you compare the `ExtendedColor` with `java.awt.Color.GREEN` then without using `XSSFColor`?

Comment: Take your current code, replace `XSSFColor` with `ExtendedColor` and you're done! `XSSFColor` extends from `ExtendedColor`, but the former isn't in the core POI jar while the latter is